# mapped null pointer value

Tags: c++, dictionary

In my code, I have a `std::map` that looks something like this:

```
std::map<std::string, A*> myMap;
```

where A is one of my custom classes.

When I access a map element which does not exist via `operator[]` like so:

```
std::string s("hello");
A* pA = myMap[s];
```

I know that a new element will be created with that key but I would like the pointer to be initialized to NULL. In other words, if `myMap[s]` exists, a valid pointer should be returned. If not, I would like pA to be NULL after the above code executes.

By default, will pA contain garbage if `myMap[s]` doesn't exit? How can I make it so that pA contains the value NULL if the element doesn't exit?

Comment: It will be a nullptr if the key was not present before your invoke. The map-value  of such a resulting auto-insertion, in your case a pointer type, is value-initialized, and a value-intialized pointer per the standard is zero-initialized, which is synonymous to a nullptr. Ie. you get it for free.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to elaborate? I explained exactly what I was trying to achieve and asked a question about the default behavior in provided situation.

Comment: @user974967 The question shows no research effort (i.e. you didn't even try to read the manual).

Comment: @melpomene manual? what manual is that? You mean the standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes, your pointer can reliably be considered a `nullptr` on a new key lookup with no prior value.

Long Answer:

Per the standard:

> **C++11 § 23.4.4.3,p5**
>
> `T& operator[](key_type&& x);`
>
> *Effects*: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts `value_type(std::move(x), T())` into the map.

Note particularly the use of **`T()`**, where `T` in this case is your pointer type. This leads to...

> **C++11 § 8.5,p10**
>
> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., **()**, shall be **value-initialized**.

By the definition of *value initialization*:

> **C++11 § 8.5,p7**
>
> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is **zero-initialized** and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is **zero-initialized.**

Which brings us to what it means for your object-type to be zero-initialized:

> **C++11 § 8.5,p5**
>
> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - **if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), taken as an integral constant expression, converted to T <sub>(103)</sub>**
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) union type, the object’s first non-static named data member is zero- initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
> - if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.
>
> 103) As specified in 4.10, converting an integral constant expression whose value is 0 to a pointer type results in a **null pointer value**.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question and the helpful info.

Answer (score 2):

Yes new elements in map for embedded types like int or pointer are zero-initialized, so your pointer will be NULL.